# How to center a CSS element under another in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dashboard

I'm designing a Shiny app, and have an absolute panel that I'd like to have a dashboard-esque look.

Essentially, I have a few text-descriptions of buttons that I'd like to appear in the dashboard, with the buttons appearing centered underneath the text descriptions. I've currently used the absolute position control in CSS to determine the placement within the panel. While this works for now, I don't think it is a particularly scaleable method.

I have attached some reproducible code, so that you have an idea of what I'm talking about.

Thanks so much for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  absolutePanel(
    id = "quick-glance", style="z-index:500; opacity: 0.90",
    class = "panel panel-default",
    draggable=TRUE,
    fixed=TRUE,
    width = 180,
    height = 75,
    top = 20, left = 50,

    textOutput("label1"), tags$head(tags$style("#label1{
                                               color: steelblue;
                                               font-weight: bold; 
                                               border: none;
                                               position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 30px;
                                               ")),
    actionBttn("bttn1",label = "$##",style = "bordered",color = "primary"),
    tags$head(tags$style("#bttn1{ position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 20px;}")),

    textOutput("label2"),tags$head(tags$style("#label2{
                                              color: steelblue;
                                              font-weight: bold; 
                                              border: none;
                                              position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 100px;
                                              ")),
    actionBttn("bttn2",label = "#",style = "bordered",color = "danger"),
    tags$head(tags$style("#bttn2{ position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 110px;}"))


    )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$bttn1 = renderPrint(input$bttn1)
  output$label1 = renderText("Text")

  output$label2 = renderText("Text Text")
  output$bttn2 = renderPrint(input$bttn2)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to wrap the things you want grouped in a `column()`, which creates a `div` you can then center. Then, within each such `div` you can center the text and the button.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  absolutePanel(
    id = "quick-glance", style="z-index:500; opacity: 0.90",
    class = "panel panel-default",
    draggable=TRUE,
    fixed=TRUE,
    width = 180,
    height = 75,
    top = 20, left = 50,
    fluidRow(
      column(
        textOutput("label1"), 
        actionBttn("bttn1",label = "$##",style = "bordered",color = "primary"),
        width = 1
      ),
      column(
        textOutput("label2"), 
        actionBttn("bttn2",label = "#",style = "bordered",color = "danger"),
        width = 1
      )
    ),
    tags$head(tags$style(".col-sm-1 {width: 50%; margin: 0px;}
                          #label1, #bttn1, #label2, #bttn2 {margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; text-align: center}"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$bttn1 = renderPrint(input$bttn1)
  output$label1 = renderText("Text")

  output$label2 = renderText("Text Text")
  output$bttn2 = renderPrint(input$bttn2)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks for your help! One issue, that I guess I hadn't foreseen: so one of the values that will be in the action button's is much longer than any of the other values in the other buttons. With the solution above, this means that all of the action button's have a large border, with lots of whitespace (because the button's are all the same size). Is there a way to automatically adjust the size of the button border to the length of the content? Thanks!

Comment: I think if you remove the `width: 100%;` in the CSS, the button width will be the size of its content. However, if you do that, it will probably no longer be centered. I don't know how to fix that, you could search for some CSS documentation to fix that.

Comment: You're right, it no longer stays centered then. I'll do some reading! Either way, thanks for your help!